# Python pandas DataFrame loc selection for a range of rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, pandas-loc

Here is a head() of my DataFrame df:

```
                     Temperature  DewPoint  Pressure
Date                                                
2010-01-01 00:00:00         46.2      37.5       1.0
2010-01-01 01:00:00         44.6      37.1       1.0
2010-01-01 02:00:00         44.1      36.9       1.0
2010-01-01 03:00:00         43.8      36.9       1.0
2010-01-01 04:00:00         43.5      36.8       1.0
```

I want to select from August 1 to August 15 2010 and display only the Temperature column.

What I am trying to do is:
df.loc[['2010-08-01','2010-08-15'],'Temperature']

But this is throwing me an error.

Generally speaking what I want to learn is how, using loc method I can easily take a range of row i to row k and column j to p and show it in dataframe using loc method:

df.loc[[i:k],[j:p]]

Thank you very much in advance!!!
Steve

Comment: does `df['Temperature'].loc['2010-08-01':'2010-08-15']` work?

Comment: EdChum, yes it works, but why can't I do the same with loc[[i:k],[j:p]]?
Why I need to "externally" define on what column I work?
What if I want 2 columns?

Comment: For example this won't work:
df['Temperature','DewPoint'].loc['2010-08-01':'2010-08-15']

Comment: The issue here is that slice ranges with partial date string matching may not work here, it's the datetime that is the issue

Comment: That's a syntax error should be `df[['Temperature','DewPoint']].loc['2010-08-01':'2010-08-15']` you need additional square brackets, it would evern without the `loc`

Comment: That is why I am asking you, like in Matlab you can select rows i to j,
columns j to p and get sub matrix.
Here I want "sub data frame" in a range of specific dates.
Is it possible?

Comment: EdChum, yep my mistake it worked, thanks a lot!
But I am still a bit confused if it's possible to do the selection the way I have shown in my question:
df.loc[[i:k],[j:p]]
Or I should do this by df[ [i,......,k] ].loc[ j:p ]

Comment: I think you want to use `ix`: `df.ix['2010-01-01':, 'DewPoint':]` would give you a sliced view of the rows and columns, check the docs:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Exactly!!!!
So this is done by ix.
Thank you very much EdChum!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think if you want to be able to pass a slice for the index and columns then you can use `ix` to achieve this:

```
In [19]:
df.ix['2010-01-01':, 'DewPoint':]

Out[19]:
                     DewPoint  Pressure
Date                                   
2010-01-01 00:00:00      37.5       1.0
2010-01-01 01:00:00      37.1       1.0
2010-01-01 02:00:00      36.9       1.0
2010-01-01 03:00:00      36.9       1.0
2010-01-01 04:00:00      36.8       1.0
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) detail numerous ways of selecting data